How to navigate into an array (JSON) without knowing the label in PHP?
I have a complex multidimensional array, which I'm flipping in all directions and I'm lost extracting the data. This is a list of questions, with its properties, including in particular a table with possible answers (quiz management):
{
  "questions": {
    "jvaso": {
      "id": "jvaso",
      "mediaType": "image",
      "answerType": "text",
      "imageCredit": "",
      "image": "https://zzz.fr/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/B737NG-Landing-Gear-Gear-red-light.jpg",
      "imageId": "4184",
      "video": "",
      "imagePlaceholder": "",
      "imagePlaceholderId": "",
      "title": "Landing Gear Indicator Lights - What does this indication mean?",
      "desc": "",
      "hint": "",
      "answers": {
        "c0xpi": {
          "id": "c0xpi",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Landing gear is not down and locked (with either or both forward thrust levers retarded to idle, and below 800 feet AGL). Related landing gear is in disagreement with LANDING GEAR lever\r\nposition (in transit or unsafe).",
          "isCorrect": "1"
        },
        "b9086": {
          "id": "b9086",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Landing gear is not down and locked (with either or both forward thrust levers retarded to idle, and below 1000 feet AGL). Related landing gear is in disagreement with LANDING GEAR lever\r\nposition."
        },
        "xdkdh": {
          "id": "xdkdh",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Landing gear is not down and locked (with thrust levers in idle, and below 800 feet AGL). Related landing gear is in disagreement with LANDING GEAR lever."
        },
        "9i4a8": {
          "id": "9i4a8",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Landing gear is not down and locked. Related landing gear is in disagreement with LANDING GEAR lever position (in transit or unsafe)."
        }
      }
    },
    "da3gw": {
      "id": "da3gw",
      "mediaType": "image",
      "answerType": "text",
      "imageCredit": "",
      "image": "",
      "imageId": "",
      "video": "",
      "imagePlaceholder": "",
      "imagePlaceholderId": "",
      "title": "When the manual Extension Access Door is open:\r\n",
      "desc": "",
      "hint": "",
      "answers": {
        "07lth": {
          "id": "07lth",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Normal landing gear extension is still possible if hydraulic system B pressure is available"
        },
        "vc86n": {
          "id": "vc86n",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Manual landing gear extension is possible with landing gear lever in any position.",
          "isCorrect": "1"
        },
        "hc4c9": {
          "id": "hc4c9",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Normal landing gear extension is still possible if hydraulic system A pressure is available"
        },
        "cg5yq": {
          "id": "cg5yq",
          "image": "",
          "imageId": "",
          "title": "Landing gear retraction is enabled."
        }
      }
    },

My problem is that I don't know the label (id) of the first column of the "questions" array
I tried several things, including:
$arr = json_decode($contenu, true);
        
    foreach($arr[0]['questions'] as $key=>$val){
        foreach($val[0] as $keys=>$value){
            $donnees .= $value['title'].'<br>';
        }  
    }

but I've tried so many things that I'm drowning.
If anyone could give me a little help, I'd appreciate it.
THANKS !

The arrays are all associative, not indexed, so you don't need [0].
$donnees = '';
foreach ($arr['questions'] as $question) {
    $donnees .= "Question: " . $question['title'] . "<br>\nAnswers:<br>\n";
    foreach ($question['answers'] as $answer) {
        $donnees .= $answer['title'] . "<br>";
    }
}
echo $donnees;


Thank you very much !!!
I had to add "[0]" between "$arr" and "['questions']" and it works

I don't see why unless there's another level of array that you didn't show above.
